# Placeholder losing data after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm reading a list of id numbers from a database table into a placeholder textbox but however; if I do a button click the data is removed.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     while (myReader.Read())
        {


            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Text = (string)myReader["idNumber"];
            txt.ID = "txt" + i;
            txt.ReadOnly = true;
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));

            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Could show the button click event where you retrieve those textboxes?

Comment: @Win, the btnsearch is where I create the textbox and read the data into it

Comment: Controls added dynamically have to be added again during the next page_load.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but please learn about how to use CSS to add padding to an element rather than use non-breaking spaces like that... Future maintainers of your code will thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem when working with dynamically added controls in web forms (especially if you're coming from a winforms background). Pages in ASP.NET Web Forms are stateless, and reconstructed on each postback. Therefore, if you add a control to a page during a server event, you'll also have to add it to the page on subsequent Page loads if you want it to appear. You can accomplish this with something similar to the following:

```
protected List<Control> ControlCache
{
    get => (List<Control>)(Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = (Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] as List<Control>) ?? new List<Control>());
    set => Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = value;
}

/* If you can't use C# 7's expression bodied property accessors, here's the equivalent in blocks:
protected List<Control> ControlCache
{
    get { return (List<Control>)(Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = (Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] as List<Control>) ?? new List<Control>()); }
    set { Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = value; }
}
*/

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (var control in ControlCache)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
            ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        }
    }
    else
        ControlCache = null;
}


protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Text = (string)myReader["idNumber"];
        txt.ID = "txt" + i;
        txt.ReadOnly = true;
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        ControlCache.Add(txt);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error { or ; expected and I'm not seeing what I'm missing. Works fine on the local machine but i put in on the server i'm getting that error

Comment: @Jane On which lines is it occurring? The ControlCache property?

Comment: get => (List<Control>)(Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] = (Session["cachedControlsForPageX"] as List<Control>) ?? new List<Control>());

Comment: @Jane I've updated the answer with a pre-C# 7 compatible implementation for that property.

Comment: is possible to stop the textboxes from add on each button click; because also wanted to created textboxes based on the number selected from a dropdown list populates the number of textboxes. If I choose 2; then 3 then it is added up to five textboxes

Comment: @Jane If you want to change the text boxes each time you click, null out the ControlCache at the beginning of the click event.

Comment: protected void ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    int count = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCount.SelectedItem.Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
ControlCache = null;
        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.MaxLength = 10;

        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
        ControlCache.Add(tx);

    }

Comment: I have that but it seems to be adding an extra textbox